# How Does One Begin to Read Mathematical Journals and Papers?

Tags: soft-question, education

I am an undergraduate CS student but I love mathematics and spend most of my time doing and reading math books. I realize that it's important to get into the habit of reading papers and journals so it will be easier to think of ideas for projects and research.

I'd like to know how I should start reading papers and what papers are good for beginners?

The areas of mathematics I really like are Discrete Mathematics, Combinatorics, Number Theory, Mathematical Induction, Problem Solving, etc. I like things like Calculus too but I feel papers on Calculus would be too difficult to understand.

Also, are there any particular efficient methodologies for reading papers? Is knowledge better gotten from books or from papers?

Note: I want to say that there are already threads asking which papers every mathematician should read, and which every computer scientist should read. The purpose of this thread is slightly different. It isn't asking which standard papers everyone should know. It's asking which papers allow for an incisive entry into deeper knowledge of the subject.

P.S. : For the benefit of anyone who sees this thread later, I did find a wonderful journal called `Crux Mathematicorum'' dedicated solely to problem solving! They allow free access to their back issues on their website. Other good journals I found were`Parabola'' and ``Pi in The Sky,'' both of which may be read online for free.

Comment: Relevant: http://blog.geomblog.org/2016/01/reading-with-purpose-grand-experiment.html and http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/2180/13319

Comment: Papers in most subsubfields of math require some relevant background both in general experience with formal mathematics and content knowledge. Sometimes an undergrad intro to combinatorics is enough, but often much more specialized knowledge is required. Without a particular paper you'd like to read, I'd say just start with undergrad/graduate textbooks first and then branch out into real papers.

Comment: Do you know of any good papers dealing with problem solving, perhaps ? Those problems don't require too much knowledge but test skill.

Comment: I'm not sure how much research there is on problem solving, and if there were any, I would expect it to belong more to the educational side of the spectrum, rather than being focused primarily on mathematical content. That said, George Polya concentrated quite a bit on problem solving, and you may want to look into any of this books, in particular, *How to Solve It*.

Comment: I'm looking for journals/books of a similar spirit as Polya's book.

Comment: "I feel papers on Calculus would be too difficult to understand."  I'm not sure what you mean by this because math papers are about math research, and calculus (and also problem solving) isn't an active area of math research.  So I would say there pretty much aren't any recent papers about calculus.  You could find papers about advanced topics that build on calculus, of course, but I think usually people read graduate level textbooks in a particular area before they're able to understand recent papers published in that area.

Comment: @littleO I didn't know research isn't done in calculus. What I meant is open problems and general language of calculus or analysis are more intimidating to understand because they have a lot of jargon, unlike number theory and combinatorics where questions like " Is there an odd perfect number?" are easier to understand. Not to say I don't know calculus or don't like it, but I think any modern work on it would be completely inaccessible. I'm pretty sure number theoretic papers would be in accessible too but atleast I'll be able to understand the question!

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you mean by "calculus". There is a lot of research on analysis, that might be what you had in mind.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:undergraduate-research] tag. It is being removed.

Comment: @6005 This question was put up ages ago. I've lost interest in it. Why are you commenting this now ?

Comment: @user230452 As I said the tag is currently being removed, which means I was going through all questions with the tag and removing it.

Comment: @6005 Why would you do such a thing ?

Comment: @user230452 Why are you so suspicious? It's a thing we do on this site. The thread for 2016 is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22348/tag-management-2016). To remove a bad tag with under 50 questions or so, normally we just remove the tag manually from every question that used it (potentially retagging with more appropriate tags). Tags with no associated questions are then automatically deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Since, I have not gotten any answer, I will put my own answer to this question shortly. It my be of help to anyone in the future who finds this.

Comment: Polya also wrote  Mathematical Discovery: On Understanding,Learning, and Teaching Problem Solving (in two volumes) which I found  much better than his earlier How To Solve It........ Are you familiar with American Mathematical Monthly, and  its companion Mathematics Magazine?

Answer (score 0):

Try to obtain a copy (your school library probably has them) of some of the MAA publications like the *Mathematics Magazine* or the *College Math Journal*.

The *Mathematical Gazette* is also nice in my opinion for college students or advanced high school students.

The MAA also publishes the *American Mathematical Monthly*, but it may be a bot advanced for beginners.

These might be a nice place to start.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I am afraid I am no longer in school/college. :) Besides, my college library didn't have any magazine from MAA.